# How do i list the contents of a tar file

Tags: tar, archive

I tried using `-t` like the man says, but it just waits.

Example

```
$ tar -t archive.tar 
 (nothing)
```

Comment: It is waiting to read stdin, and trying to tell you about/if "archive.tar" in that stream.  What you want to do is already answered below.  Check one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I needed to add the `f` flag to tell tar I'm specifying the filename, i.e.

```
$ tar -tf archive.tar
file1.txt
file2.txt
$
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also increase the number of details listed:

```
$ tar -tvf archive.tar
-rw-r--r--  0 user group       0  3 Dez 00:21 file1.txt
-rw-r--r--  0 user group       0  3 Dez 00:21 file2.txt
```

While the -x switch is usually used to extract the whole content of an archive, you can also use it to extract a single file or directory:

```
$ tar -xvf test.tar file1.txt
x file1.txt
```

Best wishes,
Fabian